# How to send data using Json and get in asp.net services

Tags: asp.net, json, ajax, web-services, jscript

I am php developer and recently switched to asp, I want to send data to web services and get there but I am unable to come up with a solution.
In php if you want to access data for back-end process purpose we simply use 
**.Serialize();** method,

for example:

`<form id="loginForm">
<input class="form-control" name="UserEmail" placeholder="Email" type="email" required=""/>
</form>`

and in Jscript function we will serialize the form, e.g:

```
var data = $("#loginForm").serialize();
```

and in process side I can call it by inputs name, But in asp.net I am unable to do the same, I might be missing something or does asp.net do not support such approach at all? I do not know please programmers help me out.

Comment: Are you using Asp.Net webforms or Asp.Net MVC ? And you can make use of [Newtonsoft JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) library with both frameworks. Also show us some Asp.Net code how you are trying to build so that someone can quickly show an approach to fix your problem.

Comment: why dont you send them by json through id instead of name? I mean you sould try sending them by id like var id=$("input_Id").val(); and then stack them?

Comment: Siva Gopal yes dear I am sure. posting full code will be waste of time, it will make the question more lengthy I just want to know how can I get data in services and use them.

Comment: Khan even If I do that how would I get the data ? that is what i am wondering.

Comment: @naizoric You should be aware of [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and take time to go through it. Also what if contributors too feel that writing a lengthy answer(if needed) for you is of time waste!?

Comment: @SivaGopal  I apologize my friend I did not meant to offend you. I have mentioned I dont know how to get data in service so how could I share that part ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Id property and use stingify() method instead of serialization.

**HTML**

```
<input class="form-control" Id="UserEmail" placeholder="Email" type="email" required=""/>
```

**JS**

```
function YesFunction() {


        var email= $("#UserEmail").val();

        var d= [];
        d.push(email);

        var jsndta = JSON.stringify({ d: d});
                    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "wbservices/SearchSchoolInfoAndInventory.asmx/Searchschoolbesicinfo",
            data: jsnDta,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (r) {
                var rtnData = r.d; //all returned data...
                var respDta = [];
                $.map(rtnData, function (item, index) {
                    var j = [
                        item.status,
                        item.msg,
                    ];
                    respDta.push(j);
                });
                $.each(respDta, function (key, value) {
                    var status = value[0];
                    var msg = value[1];


                    if (status == true) {
                        table.html(msg);
                    } else {

                    }
                }); //1st out loop ends here...


            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                //  $("#responseMovDetails").html(jqXHR + textStatus + errorThrown);
                alert("error while loading Purchases Head" + jqXHR + textStatus + errorThrown);

            }



        });

    }
```

Now create a class and create two public variables and call both variables by creating class object in web service class.

```
    public class RequestResponse
    {
        public bool status { get; set; }
        public string msg { get; set; }
    }
[WebMethod]
        public List<RequestResponse>ActivatePBudget(List<string> d)
        {
            RequestResponse r = new RequestResponse();
            List<RequestResponse> list = new List<RequestResponse>();

            string Email= d[0].ToString();

//establish connection. I have established connection in separate class.
            DbCon dbcon = new DbCon();
            string constr = dbcon.dbconnection();
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                string CheckEmail = "select *  from Table_Name where Email= @m";
                SqlCommand getcmd= new SqlCommand(CheckEmail,con);
                getcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@m", Email);
                SqlDataReader reader=getbhidcmd.ExecuteReader();

                if(reader.Read())
                {
                    r.status = true;
                    r.msg = "Valid User Or Redirect user to another page";
                    list.Add(r);
                reader.Close();
                }
                else 
                {

                reader.Close();
                    r.status = false;
                    r.msg = "Invalid Email";
                    list.Add(r);

                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                r.status = false;
                r.msg = "Invalid Email" + ex.ToString();
                list.Add(r);
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
            return list;
        }
```

Comment: I have read your code and it seems to me this is what I was lacking, get data by calling it in parameter and a class for response.

Answer (score 0):

HTML+JS+ WEB-SERVICE
JS：

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function getProject() {
            var data = "";
            var strUser = "<%=nowUser%>";
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: '<%=AppRoot%>main/BackWebservice.asmx/LoadProjects',
                async: true,
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { strAdmin: strUser },
                success: function (result) {
                    var json = eval(result); //数组 
                    var optionstring = "";
                    $.each(json, function (index, item) {
                        //循环获取数据    
                        var name = json[index].Name;
                        var idnumber = json[index].ID;
                        optionstring += "<option value=\"" + idnumber + "\" >" + name + "</option>";
                    });
                    $("#userProject").html("<option value=\"" + 0 + "\"'>所有项目</option> " + optionstring);
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(XMLHttpRequest.status);
                    alert(XMLHttpRequest.readyState);
                    alert(textStatus);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

WEB-SERVICE

```
    [WebMethod]
public void LoadProjects(string strAdmin)
{
    List<Project> mProjects = new List<Project>();
    string stuJsonString = "";
    bool bManager = false;
    using (SqlConnection connection1 = new SqlConnection(Cfg.SqlServer))
    {
        connection1.Open();
        string mstrsql1 = "SELECT * FROM ShuiUser where 账号='" + strAdmin + "'";
        using (SqlCommand CMD1 = new SqlCommand(mstrsql1, connection1))
        {
            SqlDataReader DR1 = CMD1.ExecuteReader();
            while (DR1.Read())
            {
                if (DR1["管理"].ToString() == "1")
                {
                    bManager = true;
                }
            }
            DR1.Close();
        }
        connection1.Close();
    }
    using (SqlConnection connection2 = new SqlConnection(Cfg.SqlServer))
    {
        connection2.Open();
        string mstrsql2 = "";
        if (bManager)
        {
            mstrsql2 = "select * from ShuiProject";
        }
        else
        {
            mstrsql2 = "select a.* from ShuiProject a,ShuiUser b where a.[编号]=b.[项目] AND b.[账号]='" + strAdmin + "' ";
        }
        using (SqlCommand CMD2 = new SqlCommand(mstrsql2, connection2))
        {
            SqlDataReader DR2 = CMD2.ExecuteReader();
            while (DR2.Read())
            {
                Project mProject = new Project();
                mProject.ID = Convert.ToInt16(DR2["编号"]);
                mProject.Name = DR2["名称"].ToString();
                mProjects.Add(mProject);
            }
            DR2.Close();
        }
        connection2.Close();
    }

    stuJsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mProjects);
    //主要是下面的两句 The most important two sentences
    Context.Response.Write(stuJsonString);
    Context.Response.End();
}
```

Comment: how are you returning the result to Js function ?

Comment: I agree with @khan how you send the result/data back to Jscript

Comment: stuJsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mProjects);
//firse:make the object “mProjects”serialize
//second:The most important two sentences,send the result to js 
    Context.Response.Write(stuJsonString);
    Context.Response.End();

Answer (score 0):

ASPX:

```
<form runat=”server” id="loginForm"> 
<asp:Textbox runat=”server” cssClass="form-control" id="UserEmail" placeholder="Email" TextMode=”email” required=""/> 
</form>
```

On Codebehind(.cs):

```
 using Newtonsoft.Json;
 var obj=new {
 Email= UserEmail.Text.Trim()
 };

var j=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
```

I have assumed that you are working on webforms.

Comment: No dear I need to get them on service.asmx not on webforms.

Answer (score 0):

you must used jsonp in asp
$.ajax({
    url: 'you path',
    datatype: 'jsonp',
    data: {....}
});